# Não consigo rastrear diretório para coloca no GIT

Tags: git, github

juli-yumes-MacBook-Pro:~ juliyume$ cd documents

juli-yumes-MacBook-Pro:documents juliyume$ ls

44261182807-IRPF-2018-2017-origi-imagem-declaracao 2.pdf
    WhatsApp Image 2019-01-17 at 15.29.04 (1).jpeg
44261182807-IRPF-2018-2017-origi-imagem-declaracao.pdf
        WhatsApp Image 2019-01-17 at 15.29.04 (2).jpeg

CV Vinicius Henrique Rocha T (1).pdf
            WhatsApp Image 2019-01-17 at 15.29.04 (3).jpeg

Curriculos
                WhatsApp Image 2019-01-17 at 15.29.04.jpeg

Curso Front-End
                WhatsApp Image 2019-01-18 at 13.22.29 (1).jpeg

EUA
            WhatsApp Image 2019-01-18 at 13.22.29 (1)_Easy-Resize.com.jpg

Fotos Perfil
                            WhatsApp Image 2019-01-18 at 13.22.29.jpeg

OFFICIALHIST.pdf
                        WhatsApp Image 2019-01-18 at 13.22.29_Easy-Resize.com.jpg

Profile.pdf
                            doc01667720180912133847.pdf

ProgramasRFB
                            relHistoricoOficialWeb.php

**juli-yumes-MacBook-Pro:documents juliyume$ cd curso front-end**
**-bash: cd: curso: No such file or directory**

Estou tentanto acessar a pasta "Curso Front-End" que está dentro de "Documents" mas quando dou --> CD Curso Front-End .... Aparece mensagem "No such file or directory" ... Eu acredito que isso se deva ao nome da pasta conter ESPAÇOS mas tb não consegui testar essa teoria, pois se mudo o nome da minha pasta, meus projetos dentro dela se perdem ... HELP!

Comment: Sim, é por causa do espaço, basta usar um ``\``, assim: `cd Curso\ Front-End`. Se não me engano, colocar entre aspas também funciona: `cd "Curso Front-End"`

Comment: DEU CERTO HEHEHE! Obrigado, ser noob é tenso... valeuuuu